# Retrofit 2 Android Deserializer JSON GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

Acabo de empezar con Retrofit 2 para Android, me he decantando por el por la buenas criticas que tenia, aunque me hubiera quedado con Volley ya que lo veo bastante mas fácil.

El caso es que me esta dando bastante la lata el tema de deserializar los JSON con GSON.

Pongo el código para que se entienda:

Me he creado un Singleton para gestionar las conexiones de toda la app, espero que este bien:

```
public class SingletonRetrofit {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new GenericDeserializer<User>())
                        .create();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Luego me he creado el siguiente deserializer "genérico", y ahora explico porque según yo he entendido, pero aquí me gustaría que me corrigierais si me estoy equivocando:

```
    public class GenericDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T>
{
    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
            throws JsonParseException
    {
        // Get the "content" element from the parsed JSON
        JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("type");


        if(content.toString().equals("\"dbUserResponse\"")){
            content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("user");

            JsonObject jsonObject = content.getAsJsonObject();
            if(jsonObject.has("nacimiento")){
                String date = jsonObject.get("nacimiento").getAsString();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                Date date2 = null;
                try {
                    date2 = sdf.parse(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date2);
                jsonObject.addProperty("nacimiento", newstring);
                content = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject();  
                }
            }

        }
        if(content.toString().equals("\"dbAlertResponse\"")){
        // other case..... etc...

        }

        else{
            //content = '{"error":"mierror"}';
        }


        // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
        // to this deserializer
        return new Gson().fromJson(content, type);

    }
}
```

Y ahora donde yo quiero hago la llamada a mi API:

```
//METODO CON RETROFIT
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        pDialog.show();
        final String TAG = RegisterUser.class.getSimpleName();


        ApiInterface apiService = SingletonRetrofit.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);


        Call<User> call = apiService.getUser(1);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, retrofit2.Response<User> response) {
                User userdatos = response.body();

                if(userdatos != null){
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).setText(userdatos.getEmail());
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateBirth)).setText(userdatos.getNacimiento().toString());

                }
                else{
                    //Toast.makeText(PersonalProfileActivity.this, "Error al cargar usuario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                pDialog.hide();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User>call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, "error a la M");
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Bueno expongo mis problemas:

1º - No consigo formatear una fecha que me llega en el JSON siguiente:

```
{
  "type": "dbUserResponse",
  "user": {
    "email": "canadas@canada.es",
    "nacimiento": "1995-01-01T00:00:00+01:00",
  }
}
```

Todas las respuestas de las llamadas me llegan en este "estilo". Es decir, "type" indica que tipo de respuesta es. Por ejemplo para el caso de "alertas" me llegaría "type" : "dbAlertResponse".

Por esta razón me he creado un deserializer genérico, pero yo no se si es lo correcto. Ademas como os digo, me es imposible que el formato de fecha que me esta llegando sea convertido al que me interesa que seria "yyyy-MM-dd".

2º-He intentado añadir otro deserializerTypeAdapter en la creación del gson, pero o no se como se hace, o no me ha funcionado.

¿Cómo se resolvería correctamente esta situación?
gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado.
Estaba confundiendo conceptos.

Al tener el campo nacimiento en Date, solo tenia que formatear la fecha antes de mostrarla en la pantalla y listo :-S. No sé porque pensé que al objeto Date se le podía formatear la fecha internamente.